# multiple joins based on four tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following five tables:

```
users(user_id(pk),username)
year_month(id(pk),year_id(FK),month_id(FK))
monthly_payment(id(pk), username, amount, year_month_id(fk),user_id(fk))
years(year_id(pk),year)
month(month_id(pk),month_name)
```

I have 4 users registered in `users` table, 3 years in `year_month` table and some records in `monthly_payment` table (which store amount each user paid monthly).

**I tried a lot to make a query that get all the years with months for each user, and show for each user if the `amount` field in the `monthly_payment` table is set with number or it's still empty.**

this is the query I made:

```
select ym.id, ym.year_id,y.year, m.month_name, ym.month_id, mp.amount, u.user_id, u.username, u.`first_name`, u.`last_name`
from `users` as u
left join monthly_payment as mp using(user_id)
right join `year_month` as ym on(ym.id = mp.`year_month_id`)
inner join `years` as y on(y.year_id = ym.year_id)
inner join `month` as m on(m.month_id = ym.month_id)
where mp.year_month_id is null or mp.year_month_id is not null
```

will, the result is different than what I thought. it just show me **the years only one time.**

can anyone guide me how to do it correctly?!!
and thanks,

Comment: Can you prepare a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) data sample?

Comment: Maybe get rid of the years table, the months table, and the year_month table.

Comment: @Strawberry, I tried to do that, still did not works. thank you!

Comment: @JorgeCampos, here is the sample: [mySampleData](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/729c4/3/0), and thanks.

Comment: In addition to CREATE and INSERT statements, it's often useful to provide the desired result - and in the main body of the question, rather than in the comments area.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your year_month table, and left join all the other tables. As soon as you use an ordinary inner join, you run the chance of suppressing some date values with no matching items.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your help.

but it gives me an error, just can you tell me if the order(of joining tables together) here is right or not?:

`select ym.*, mp.*, u.user_id, u.username, y.year, m.month_name 
from year_month as ym 
left join monthly_payment as mp on(ym.id = mp.year_month_id) 
left join users as u on(u.user_id = mp.user_id)
left join month as m on(m.month_id = ym.month_id)
left join years as y on(y.year_id = ym.year_id)
where mp.year_month_id is null or mp.year_month_id is not null`